# Does $\int_0^1 f(x)=\int_0^1 xf(x)$ imply $\int_0^x f(t)$ has a root

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

My question is whether or not the following is true:

If $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continous function such that
$$\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\int_0^1 xf(x)dx$$
then there exist $c\in(0,1)$ such that
$$\int_0^c f(x)dx=0$$

It is quite clear that in the interval $(0,1)$ there must be some points $a$ such that $f(1)f(a)<0$ but I can't say from this if the statement above is true or not.

Comment: Do you have an example of a non-zero function that satisfies the first equality?

Comment: @Yanko $\operatorname{sinc}(2\pi (1-x) )$ works

Comment: @Yanko Surley there are such functions. There exist $a,b$ such that $ax+b$ satisfies that equation.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Right, for $a=6,b=-2$. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F(x)=\int_0^{x} f(t)\, dt$. Then $F(1)=\int_0^{1} f(t)\, dt=\int_0^{1} tf(t)\, dt=tF(t)|_0^{1}-\int_0^{1}F(t)\, dt$. This gives $\int_0^{1}F(t)\, dt=0$. If $F$ has no zeros then it is strictly positive or strictly negative throughout and its integral cannot be $0$. Hence $F(c)=0$ for some $c$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Note that
$$
\int_0^1 F(x)dx =\int_0^1\left(\int_0^x f(t)dt\right)dx=\int_0^1\left(\int_t^1dx\right)f(t)dt= \int_0^1 (1-t)f(t)dt
$$ where $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt$.