# $L^1$ norm minimization with a functional constraint

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization

Let $f\in L^1(0,1)$ then we have the optimization problem:
$$ \min_f~\lVert f\rVert_1 = \int_0^1 \lvert f(x) \rvert dx, ~~~\text{subject to}\\ F(f) = \int_0^1xf(x)dx = 1.$$

On first glance:
$$
1 = \left\lvert \int_0^1xf(x)dx \right\rvert\leq \int_0^1 x\lvert f(x)\rvert dx\leq \int_0^1 \lvert f(x) \rvert dx = \lVert f \rVert_1,
$$
so the norm is bounded from below by 1. The best approximation that I found is $f_n(x) = (n+2)x^n$, so that:
$$
\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:F(f_n) = \int_0^1(n+2)x^{n+1}dx= 1,
$$
and
$$
\lVert f_n \rVert_1 = \int_0^1(n+2)x^n = \frac{n+2}{n+1}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1
$$
My question is, does such a function (not) exist such that the bound is attained, and if it does (not), how to show it? Is the answer related to this question - [Does $\int_0^1 f(x)=\int_0^1 xf(x)$ imply $\int_0^x f(t)$ has a root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3062662/does-int-01-fx-int-01-xfx-imply-int-0x-ft-has-a-root) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the minimum is attained, then somehow all your inequalities must be tight. Suppose that there exists $f$ such that $||f||_1=1$ and $F(f)=1$. Then:

$$\int_{0}^{1} x|f(x)| dx=\int_{0}^{1} |f(x)| dx$$

ie:

$$\int_{0}^{1} (1-x)|f(x)| dx=0$$

The function $x\mapsto (1-x)|f(x)|$ is nonnegative and its integral is 0, so it must be zero almost everywhere, and it follows that $f$ is 0 almost everywhere. This contradicts the fact that $\int |f|=1$.

Comment: Isn't the equality supposed to be $\int_0^1xf(x)dx = \int_0^1\lvert f(x) \rvert dx$?
EDIT: Nevermind, thanks for the answer.